# How to refer to different queue names in the multi-worker Celery environment?

Tags: celery

I start Celery worker like the following:

`celery multi start celery1@turing.lan celery2@turing.lan -A tserver.app -Q celery,hq1 -c 8 -l info`

I am looking for a way to have an extra queue called 'high' that I want only celery2@turing.lan worker to subscribe to. According to the documentation following should work, but it does not:

`celery multi start celery1@turing.lan celery2@turing.lan -A tserver.app -Q:celery1@turing.lan celery,hq1 -c 8 -l info`

`... -Q:1 celery,hq1` does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `start` from the command. You can use the following command to start two workers which consumes `celery` queue and 2nd worker consumes `high` queue also.

```
$ celery multi start celery1@turing.lan celery2@turing.lan \
   -Q:1 celery -Q:2 celery,high -c 8 -l INFO -A tserver.app
```

More examples on how to use [celery multi is documented here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.multi.html?highlight=multi).

Looks like it's a bug in celery command line option parser. However you use this command for now as an alternative.

```
$ celery multi start celery1 celery2  \
  -Q:1 celery,hq1 -Q:2 celery,high,hq1 -c 8 -l INFO -n turing.lan
```

It was a bug in celery and I have [submitted a patch for that](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/3218).

Comment: It was a typo - I did have "start" in the command, yet it did not subscribe to the correct queue... I have even made an issue regarding this, on GitHub: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3211

Comment: @DejanLekic Please check updated answer and see if it works.